# SQL distinct records but filter nulls for one field

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL and looking for some help here. Please see the first screenshot. the first two records have exact values except for the `country` field. the second screenshot is what I want to retrieve. I want to get the first one (with a not-null `country`). I also want to keep the third record since it's the only record for `id` 345, although it has a null `country`. I tried the following query but didn't get me the results I want. [image]

[image: DESIRED RESULT]

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, first, last, age, gender, city, state, zip
FROM Person
WHERE country IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This can be done in a few different ways, but first a few questions for you... Presumably id should be used as a primary key in the table, why do you even have two rows for the same id? Then, the first two rows are NOT identical even besides the country; one shows Houston and the other dallas. Or is that a typo? Finally, do you want "what you want" only for country? What if one row shows race and the other shows NULL for race? Etc.?

Comment: And what does this have to do with PL/SQL? What you posted is plain SQL, and the solution is very likely to be plain SQL as well.

Comment: thanks mathguy for your reply. (1) the records above are from a view which are from a few joined tables. (2) sorry, it's typo. I made the changes. (3) yes, the difference should be only the country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
select   id, first, last, age, gender, city, state, zip, min(country)
from     persons
group by id, first, last, age, gender, city, state, zip
```

should work, since by default the ordering of varchar2 values is ascending and nulls are last.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `row_number` analytic function to do this.

By partitioning by `id` and then filtering by `rn = 1`, we ensure that we get no more than one row per distinct `id` value.

The `order by` clause in the `row_number` function is what determines *which* row gets returned.  In this case, rows with a non-null `country` value are prioritized.  If you have more complex rules to determine which row you want to return per `id`, just adjust the `order by` clause accordingly.

```
select id, first, last, age, gender, city, state, zip, country
  from (select id, first, last, age, gender, city, state, zip, country
               row_number() over(
                 partition by id
                     order by case when country is not null then 1 else 2 end) as rn
          from tbl)
 where rn = 1
```